# Add a little image to chapter name

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer, chapters

I would like to add a little image to every Chapter, so I defined a macro with `newcommand` with an adjustable scale and tried to rename the chapter name. This is my MWE (actually, it doesn't work because the little image does not appear)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\image}[1]{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale= #1] \draw[fill=blue] (0,0) circle(4pt); \end{tikzpicture} }
\addto\captionspanish{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{\image{0.18} Capítuloss}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{No name}
no named chapter
\end{document}
```

How I can make this small change?
Does this will also leave the small picture in the header as name of the chapter?

Comment: Your example does not load package `tikz`.

Comment: oh, but this is is not the problem, I forgot write `usepackage{tikz}` while I was wrinting my question.

Comment: I assume some missing `\protect` and your tikzpicture environment isn't closed

Comment: Thanks anyway. What is `\protect`? how can I enable it or change it?

Comment: Never type in an example, always copy from your test file. Else you will  miss loading a package or forget closing the tikzpicutre.

Comment: @Johannes_B My test file is a whole book that i'm writing. It has +5000 lines and a lot of configurations

Comment: Are you always starting with the real deal? I tend to start with a little test case, if that works i can use my real document. And if that doesn't work, i know my document is faulty. 5000 lines, hard to find the cause there.

Comment: @Johannes_B You're right. I'll start testing little docs and see if it works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `\renewcommand{\chaptername}{...}` is possible `\addto\captionsspanish{...}` of course too. (Former trial version had a typo, that's why `\addto\....` didn't work)

Anyway, `\image` is fragile due to the moving argument of `\chapter` and must be `\protect`ed.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\image}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1]
    \draw[fill=blue] (0,0) circle(4pt);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{\protect\image{0.18}Capítulos}}


\begin{document}

\chapter{No name}
no named chapter
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works. I'll look more about `protect`. Thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't you prefer `\addto\captionsspanish` instead of `\AtBeginDocument`?

Comment: @egreg: Because I made a typo and that's why it didn't work with `\addto...`